# Extracting contents from a webpage and comparing using Java

Tags: java, javascript

I am developing a Java project in which i have a sub-module where i need to extract contents [text, image, color] from a webpage and compare it with another webpage. I am planning to use WinHTTrack software for downloading the webpage locally, but the problem is it doesn't save it as HTML. How can i download a webpage with HTML extension using softwares such as WinHTTrack [or just saving the webpage through ctrl+s is enogh.?]. Also i am planning to use HTML Parsers to extract the 3 content types[text, image, color],after downloading the webpage locally. So which parser to go with.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WEll I use Httrack and it fetches html files as well.  You are probably taking winhttrack project file as the only output file, but if you check inside the project directory there are html files (together with images, etc).  I would suggest using - http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/.  It is a java library and since your project is a Java project it should be fairly easy to use it.  You can also save the whole website locally using org.htmlparser.parserapplications.SiteCapturer (and specify whether resources such as images should be captured as well).  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will check it out as you said, inside HTTrack's directory. Regarding parser, i too have read good comments about "HTMLParser". Well i will start using it and let you know. For comparison, i mean for comparing text, image, color of one webpage with another what should i do.?

Comment: Glad I could help.  Comparison is another case and thus you need to make another question

Comment: Ok i will make another question about it. Can you explain how to use HTMLParser to extract contents after i downloaded the pages to the local disk.?

Comment: Is there any tutorial for HTMLParser available.?